# Can I return a function constructor and use in other function

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, return, self-invoking-function

Let's say I've something like this:-

```
let allDataStuff = () => {
    // declare data info
    let people = {
        name: "",
        cars: [],
        bikes: []
    }

    // cars data - function contructor
    let Cars = function(id, name, brand) {
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
        this.brand = brand
    }

    // bikes data - function contructor
    let Bikes = function(id, name, brand, noOfWheels) {
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
        this.brand = brand
        this.noOfWheels = noOfWheels
    }

    // return all
    return { people, Cars, Bikes }
}
```

I can access `people` data in **other** `function` like normal *(as shown below)*

```
let createNewPeopleData = () => { // other function
    // get people data info
    let peopleData = allDataStuff().people
    console.log(peopleData) // this will log out all data currently store in the object
}
```

But I can't seem to access `Cars` and `Bikes` `function constructor` like the way I did with getting people data as show above. Currently I have something like this:-

```
let createNewPeopleData = () => { // other function
    // let's just say I've values in all these vars define below

    // create new car data 
    let newCar = allDataStuff().Cars(id, carName, carBrand) // this throw error 
    // push it into array of cars
    allDataStuff().people[cars].push(newCar)

    // create new bike data 
    let newBike = allDataStuff().Bikes(id, bikeName, bikeBrand, noOfWjeels) this throw error
    // push it into array of cars
    allDataStuff().people[bikes].push(newBike)
}
```

It says `allDataStuff is not a function`. What I **want** is **to be able to access** the `Cars` and `Bikes` function constructor **from other function** (*like show above*). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to instantiate with `new` keyword:

```
let createNewPeopleData = () => {
    let peopleData = allDataStuff()
    let car = new peopleData.Cars(1,'Yamaha XYZ', 'Yamaha')
    console.log(car)
}
```